# Override Dockerfile Entrypoint with Python and parameters/

Tags: python, docker

in my Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "start1.py"]
```

When I run the docker image i want to override it with `start2.py` with a parameter `year=2020`. So I run:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint python3 start2.py year 2020 b43ssssss
```

It still runs `start1.py`, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> It still runs start1.py, what am i doing wrong?

Because anything pass as `CMD` with the entrypoint `ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "start1.py"]` will be pass as **an argument to python file** `start1.py`.
You can verify this by doing the following

```
import argparse, sys
print  ("All ARGs",sys.argv[1:])
```

So the output will be

```
All ARGs ['start2.py', 'year', '2020', 'b43ssssss']
```

So Convert entrypoint to `python3` only with some default `CMD` (start1.py) so you will have control which files to run.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
# Default file to run
CMD ["start1.py"]
```

and then override at run time

```
docker run -it --rm my_image start2 year 2020 b43ssssss
```

Now the args should be

```
All ARGs ['year', '2020', 'b43ssssss']
```

Answer (score 1):

For a couple of reasons, I tend to recommend using `CMD` over `ENTRYPOINT` as a default.  This question is one of them: if you need to override the command at run time, it's much easier to do if you specify `CMD`.

```sh
# Change ENTRYPOINT to CMD
CMD ["python3", "start1.py"]
```

```sh
# Run an alternate script
docker run -it myimage \
  python3 start2.py year 2020 b43ssssss

# Run a debugging shell
docker run --rm -it myimage \
  bash

# Quickly double-check file contents
docker run --rm -it myimage \
  ls -l /app

# This is what you're trying to avoid
docker run --rm -it \
  --entrypoint /bin/ls \
  myimage \
  -l app
```

There is also a useful pattern of using `ENTRYPOINT` to run a secondary script that does some initial setup (waits for a database, rewrites config files, bootstraps a data store, ...) and then does `exec "$@"` to launch the `CMD`.  I tend to reserve `ENTRYPOINT` for this pattern and default to `CMD` even if I don't specifically need it.

I do not recommend splitting the command with `ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]`.  In the very specific case of wanting to run an alternate Python script it saves one word in the `docker run` command, but you still need to repeat the script name (unlike the "entrypoint-as-command" pattern) and you still need the `--entrypoint` option if you want to run something non-Python.